# How to build docker images in parallel using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile
    image: myapp/php7.0.8
    volumes:
      - "./www:/var/www/html"


  develop:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile_develop
    image: myapp/php7.0.8-dev
    volumes:
      - "./www:/var/www/html"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 7880:7880
      - 7881:7881
    links:
      - "develop:develop"
      - "base:base"
    volumes:
      - "./www:/var/www/html"
      - "./dist/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
```

That each docker image is being built. Both `develop` and `base` are being built with seperate dependencies without depending to each other. So how I can use docker-compose in order to build both `base` and `develop` in parallel in order to speed up the process?

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose build --parallel`? Found it here: [Is it possible to build docker images using docker-compose concurrently?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/is-it-possible-to-build-docker-images-using-docker-compose-concurrently)

Comment: Seems to be the case for me.